# Why can't initial length be 1 in a dynamically-allocated array?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010, dynamic-memory-allocation

Let's say we start out with:

```
int *newArray = new int[1];
```

And then later have something like:

```
ifstream inputFile("File.txt");

Counter=0;

while (inputFile >> newValue)
{
    newArray[Counter] = newValue;
    Counter++
}
```

If I try to pull 100 lines from the text file, the program will eventually crash. However, if I had used

```
int *newArray = new int[100];
```

originally, it doesn't crash.

If it's dynamically allocating memory, why does it need an initial value more than 1? That makes no sense to me. Having to define any initial length beyond a small number such as 1 or 10 defeats the whole purpose of dynamic memory allocation...

EDIT: This is for school, we aren't allowed to use vectors yet.

Comment: Because when you allocate room for only one 'int', that's all you get.  When you want more, you have to allocate more.  The dynamic aspect of the memory allocation is that you can always allocate more.  Not that it automagically grows.  If that's what you want, you want a std::vector<int>, or a class that allocates more memory as you need it.

Comment: @DavidO Nice use of the word 'automagically' :)

Comment: *"This is for school and we aren't allowed to use vectors yet."* -- What sense is there in complaining about solved problems just because you are artificially restricted from using the solutions?

Comment: @Benjamin Not complaining, just clarifying.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers and comments, you're been very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not dynamic in the sense that it can dynamically resize itself.  It's dynamic in the sense that its size can be chosen dynamically at runtime, instead of compile time.  One of the primary philosophies of C++ is that you don't pay for what you don't use.  If dynamic arrays worked the way you are asking, that would require bounds checking, something I don't need, so I don't want to pay for it.

Anyway, the problem is solved with the standard library.

```
std::vector<int> vec;
...
while (inputFile >> newValue)
{
    vec.push_back(newValue);
}
```

Isn't that much nicer?  You don't even have to keep track of the size, because vector keeps track of it for you.

If you can't use vector, then you've got a lot of work ahead of you.  The principle is essentially this.  You keep 2 additional integer variables.  One to indicate the number of values you are using in your array, and one to indicate the current capacity of your array.  When you run out of room, you allocate more space.  For example, here is a poor man's non-exception safe version of a vector:

```
int size = 0;
int capacity = 1;
int array = new int[capacity];

while (inputFile >> newValue)
{
    if (size == capacity)
    {
        capacity *= 2;
        int * newArray = new int[capacity];
        for (int i=0; i<size; ++i)
            newArray[i] = array[i];
        delete [] array;
        array = newArray;
    }
    array[size++] = newValue;    
}
```

Comment: @James: I don't subscribe to the same learning philosophy as you.  I learn by example.  Besides, the answer is not just for him.

Comment: @James: Technically homework yes, but not actually for credit so no worries in that regard :D   We ran out of time so she decided it would become an optional assignment.

Answer (score 4):

The language will not "dynamically allocate memory" for you. It is your responsibility to allocate and reallocate your arrays so that their sizes are sufficient for your purposes.

The concept of "dynamic allocation" in C++ never meant that memory will somehow allocate itself automatically for you. The word "dynamic" in this context simply means that the parameters and lifetime of the new object are determined at run time (as opposed to compile time). The primary purpose of dynamic memory allocation is: 1) to manually control object's lifetime, 2) to specify array sizes at run-time, 3) to specify object types at run-time.

The second point is what allows you to do this

```
int n = ...; // <- some run-time value
int *array = new int[n];
```

which is not possible with non-dynamically allocated arrays.

In your example, you can allocate an array if size 1 initially. Ther's nothing wrong with it. But it is still your responsibility to allocate a new, bigger array, copy the data to the new array and free the old one once you need more space in your array.

In order to avoid all that hassle you should simply use a library-provided resizable container, like `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

You're only creating space for one `int` but trying to store several, of course it crashes. Even if you created it with size 100 it'd still crash when you tried to save the 101'th value.

If you need an automatically resizing container check out `std::vector`.

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> data;

while (inputFile >> newValue)
{
    data.push_back(newValue);
}
```

This will work until your process runs out of memory.

Comment: @Sduibek Then you have to do what vector does and keep track of how full the dynamically allocated array is. If it's full then you need to create an even bigger array dynamically (oldSize * 2 should work fine), copy the contents from the old one to the new one, and then delete the old one. Is there a line in `File.txt` that tells you how big the array needs to be, perhaps?

Comment: @Sduibek Also, if they're testing your dynamic memory allocation skills then perhaps they intended you to use a linked-list?

Comment: Remember that std::vector is written in C++.  If you can't use it, you can create your own alternative.

Comment: @James, DavidO: Thank you both, that's good information for alternatives.